# Apply css control adapters to existing moss publishing site

Tags: css, sharepoint, controls

We have an existing moss publishing site. When we enable the css control adapters for our menu, they only seem to apply to newly created sites.

How can we apply this to existing sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does apply to existing sites. Make sure that after applying the control adapters you clear the .net framework temp files. This solved the problem for us.

You can also add the .browser file to the app_browsers folder in the website as opposed to adding it to the global browsers folder.

hth